# Validation in delete query in java

Tags: java, sql, validation

I have a problem in validating my delete query anything I type even if the data is not on my database it keeps deleting it says success I want it to have an error if the user type a data that is not exists in the database. Here's my code:

```
try{

    System.out.println("Enter record you want to delete: ");
    frail = scn.nextLine();

}catch(Exception ee){

    System.out.println(ee.getMessage());

}

try{    

stmt = conn.createStatement();
String sqlII = "delete from tbl_test where test_name = ?";
PreparedStatement psII = conn.prepareStatement(sqlII);
psII.setString(1, frail);
psII.executeUpdate();

    int rowAffacted = psII.executeUpdate();
       if (rowAffacted != 0) {
       System.out.println("Deleted!");
              }else{
            System.out.println("No Affected Rows!");
          }


}

catch(Exception eer){
System.out.println(eer.getMessage());               

}
```

Answer (score 1):

`psII.executeUpdate();` returns an int. If these value is zero, no lines are delete, so you can see that the user exists is not in the database and you can show an error.  Is the user is corect, the value should be grater than zero.

```
int noOfAffectedRows =psII.executeUpdate();
if (noOfAffectedRows = 0){
  //show Error
}
```

Comment: @tinker101 Can you show noOfAffectedRows in both cases? with no delete and with delete?

Comment: Hi there i use this but even there is an affected rows it still falls on no affectedrows

Comment: how can i show the noOfAffectedRows? i delete 1 row and still it falls on no Affected Rows

Comment: @tinker101 `System.out.println(noOfAffectedRows)` So you can see if the `noOfAffectedRows` is different if no record is deleted and a record is delete.

Comment: oh that sorry. It says 0 but i deleted 1 row.

Comment: @tinker101 and if no record is deleted because user not exists?

Comment: still 0, is the problem is on my database connection?

Comment: @tinker101 which database do you use? I have tried it with mysql and it gives me the result 1 if one recored is deleted and 0 if no record is deleted.

Comment: i used mysql too v 5.6

Comment: @tinker101 the the same as mine. Which mysql connector do you use?

Comment: mysql-connector-java-5.1.34-bin.jar

Comment: @tinker101 that also works fine. Are you shore, that the line is deleted when you give an existing user?

Comment: yes i have deleted many times in my database but the return count is always 0. i'll try to recreate my project maybe it's just a bug i have too many random class here

Comment: How? sorry i'm new to this

Comment: @tinker101 At the end of your question there is an "edit" link. please click and you can ass the new code.

Answer (score 1):

You could catch the return value of [executeUpdate](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeUpdate%28%29) as below:

```
int rowAffacted = psII.executeUpdate();
if (rowAffacted != 0) {
     System.out.println("Deleted!");
}
```

Javadoc for executeUpdate's return value says

```
either (1) the row count for SQL Data Manipulation Language (DML) statements or (2) 0 for SQL statements that return nothing
```

Comment: hi there i use that code and add else {
    System.out.println("no rows affected");
   } but still even if i delete a data in the database it still falls on else

Answer (score 0):

`executeUpdate()` returns the number of rows altered or returns `0` in case no rows are affected, so in your case you can do something like:

```
int alteredRows=psII.executeUpdate();
if(alteredRows==0)
{
    System.out.println("No rows deleted");
}
else
{ 
    System.out.println(alteredRows +"rows deleted");
}
```

Comment: Hi there i use your code but even if i delete a data in database it still falls on if which says "no rows deleted"

Comment: what is the value being returned from `executeUpdate()`

Comment: if you are getting the value for `alteredRows` as `1` how can it go inside `if`

Comment: oh sorry the executeUpdate() always return 0 even if i delete 1 row